# How to forward to / on 404 error in WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm developing a single page application. And I need that any HTTP request that normally produces a 404 error would forward to `/` instead. 
I mean not only API, but a static content as well.
Is it possible for WebFlux and Spring Boot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can either redirect your client to `/` or set custom content to your responses which otherwise it could have returned a `404`.

1. **Redirect to URI**: You can create a `WebFilter` component to intercept responses with `404` status code and create a permanent redirect to any given URI.

```java
@Order(-2)
@Component
public class ResourceNotFoundRedirectWebFilter implements WebFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    if (exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
      exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.PERMANENT_REDIRECT);
      exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/"));
      return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

2. **Set custom content on error**: Since you wish to forward your request and not redirect on client-side to `/` on all 404 responses you can choose to set the content returned by the handler of request to `/` (say `DefaultHandler` is the component that processes the request to `/` in this case):

```java
@Order(-2)
@Component
public class ResourceNotErrorWebFilter implements WebFilter {

  @Autowired
  ObjectMapper objectMapper;

  @Autowired
  DefaultHandler defaultHandler;

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    if (exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND) {
      exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON);
      exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK);
      byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(defaultHandler.getResponse());
      DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
      return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(buffer));
    }
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response! But this solution doesn't work for me, because at this step response always has status 200, and I need not redirect, but forward. In case of forward URL remains the same, but content is different (from `/` in my case).

Comment: So if I understand correctly you do not want to redirect your page to `/` but serve the content on the same URL that would have otherwise served on `/`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It's like forward in Servlet API.

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit. Let me know if it helps or have more questions. Not all the features in the Servlet works similarly in the reactive world. Something like `forward:/` is not supported yet.

Comment: Got your update, thanks! The issue here is that filter is invoked before exception with 404 status code thrown. That's why response in filter always has 200 status code. But I can handle it in ErrorWebExceptionHandler and check error code for exception. I will try your solution in exception handler, but not sure if this is a right approach.

Comment: Yes, I almost forgot about this case. You need to use an `@Order(-2)` on your component (in either case of `WebFilter` or `ErrorWebExceptionHandler `). Will update my answer too.